# Connecting 2 1W speakers

Tags: audio, soldering, speakers

I am trying to connect together 2 1W speakers and mount them inside some ear defenders. I am a complete novice and am following an instructable tutorial. The tutorial is a bit light on the basics and I have been unable to find any answers to my questions online. Here is a picture of the materials I am using...[image]

3.5mm headphone jack socket, 2 1W speakers, audio wire, ear defenders.

Here is a close up of the speaker...

[image]

Question1: Points A and B are copper and points 1 and 2 are something else. So my first question is do I solder the audio wire to A and B or 1 and 2 or doesn't it matter?

Here is a close up of the headphone socket and wire ends...

[image]

[image]

Question 2: Do I poke the wires through the holes and solder there? Is it white wire on one and red on the other?

Question 3: Do the red and white wires have any significance?

Here is a link to the instructable tutorial I am using.

https://www.instructables.com/id/Ear-Defender-Headphones/

I am happy with the circuit that needs to be created just not sure where to connect everything. I tried holding wires against the contacts on the speaker and on the headphone socket with sound plugged into the socket and nothing happened with the speakers. Sorry for the long question but I am completely lost. Any guidance at all would be greatly appreciated.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Typical "rubbish" instructable.  If you are capable of doing what that thing says (with all the assumptions and simplifications it makes) then you didn't need the "Instructable." If you need a tutorial to follow, then that thing is of no use.

Comment: 1 watt speakers driven anything like full blast means full sonic attack and ear destruction.

Comment: Just buy a decent set of full ear-covering noise-cancelling headphones....

Comment: Hi everyone, my apologies for the basic questions and thanks a lot for the help. I am still trying to work out were every wire goes. I have added two rather bad diagrams to my question. I am sure they are both wrong but if I was trying to get one speaker working then are either of them even close? What adjustments would be necessary? And a decent set of headphones is a good suggestion. This is just a time killing project really. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Points 1 & 2 are the soldering points for the speaker voice coil. Do not solder connecting wires on 1 & 2 as the voice coil wires may get disturbed and cause damage to the speaker.
2. Points A & B are the copper pads where the wires are to be soldered.
3. Soldering slender wires will avoid overheating and damage to the speaker.
4. The wires are to be held in the headphone jack lug holes and soldered.
5. Wire colours are only to identify 'left channel', 'right channel' and 'common'.
6. Wire as shown below.

[image]

Since you are using 8Ω 1W speakers, take care to ensure that the headphones are not plugged into a high power amplifier output which may cause hearing damage.

A power input of 10mW to the headphones may be adequate for comfortable listening. Standard headphone impedances are 32Ω and 300Ω.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was most helpful. It is the first time I've been able to get sound out of the speaker. I have edited my question by adding an altered version of your diagram. Could you tell me would this work also?

Comment: Anytime @user1821664! I am glad you got it working. The alteration you have made is quite okay and it will work for sure.

Comment: Thank you, user1821664

Answer (score 0):

First off, your ears will be happier with a lighter wire than shown.  Something in the 26-30 gauge range, maybe.

The wires solder to the tinned pads 1 and 2.  You want to do this quickly, so another reason to use smaller wire.

On the jack, the bare wires go through the holes and are folded over flat to make a good mechanical support before soldering.

Answer (score 0):

Question1: Points A and B are copper and points 1 and 2 are something else. So my first question is do I solder the audio wire to A and B or 1 and 2 or doesn't it matter?

### Ans : No, it's just the copper pad and soldering lead

Question 2: Do I poke the wires through the holes and solder there? Is it white wire on one and red on the other?

### Ans : Yes, separate it in to 2 black line, poke it. Note speak have polarity not in term of electronic but in term of sound you need to wire the same way like signal on left and ground on right

Question 3: Do the red and white wires have any significance?

### Ans : It's just convention. Red for right channel and white for left channel.